# Load/Unload Assets dynamically

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

i have to manage my RAM so want to load/unload all my ngui pages on the fly. For that i have created AssetBundle with prefabs and i'll kept those AssetBundles in my apk

What is the way to load/unload them on adroid device.

I roughly know about AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory, but unable to implement it

I am thinking in right way or missing something .

any help/??

Answer (score 2):

I think you are in the right way. Unity supports Resource Folders in the project to allow content to be supplied in the main game file yet not be loaded until requested. In Unity Pro, Unity iOS Pro(*formerly called 'iOS Advanced'*) and Unity Android Pro(*formerly called 'Android Advanced'*), you can also create Asset Bundles. These are files completely separate from the main game file which contain assets to be accessed by the game on demand from a file or URL.

An `Asset Bundle` is an external collection of assets. You can have many Asset Bundles and therefore many different external collections of assets. These files exist outside of the built Unity player, usually sitting on a web server for end-users to access dynamically.

To build an Asset Bundle, you call `BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundle()` from inside an Editor script. In the arguments, you specify an array of Objects to be included in the built file, along with some other options. This will build a file that you can later load dynamically in the runtime by using `AssetBundle.Load()`.

You can unload resources of an AssetBundle by calling `AssetBundle.Unload()`. If you pass true for the unloadAllLoadedObjects parameter, both the objects held internally by the `AssetBundle` and the ones loaded from the AssetBundle using `AssetBundle.Load()` will be destroyed and memory used by the bundle will be released.

Sometimes you may prefer to load an AssetBundle, instantiate the objects desired and release the memory used up by the bundle while keeping the objects around. The benefit is that you free up memory for other tasks, for instance loading another AssetBundle. In this scenario you would pass false as the parameter. After the bundle is destroyed you will not be able to load objects from it any more.

If you want to destroy scene objects loaded using `Resources.Load()` prior to loading another level, call `Object.Destroy()` on them. To release assets, use `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets()`.

Read the whole story in [Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).

Comment: Thanks Joetjah for your quick and brief reply
BDW can i keep AssetBudles inside my apk?
If so, how could i load them?
i know the way loading them from web server but confused with app load

Comment: When installing an APK, you can install all kind of bundles with it. That doesn't mean those bundles are loaded on every scene. Therefore it'll save you RAM since the bundles aren't accessed when not needed.

Comment: that means i have to explicitly load all assets to device right?
but what if the app is uploaded on store ?
sorry if those q's seems silly, but i m a newbie and really got stuck in this

Comment: I have some experience in it but I don't know all of it neither. I'm just making assumptions on bases of what I read. The way I see it, the APK (which you download from the store) can be huge. That'd means the mobile's ROM would get filled. But when starting the application, only the assets YOU select will be loaded. Therefore, the device's RAM won't be filled that much. Provided you know when to load/unload the right packages and make sure you don't leak anywhere, ofcourse.